# Sequence of real functions is Cauchy if and only if this same sequence if convergent $\mu-a.e.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Consider the following exercise:

**Exercise.** A sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ of real-valued functions defined in a measure space $(X,\cal{A},\mu)$ is said to be Cauchy in almost every point if

$$ \sup_{m,n \geqslant k} |f_n - f_m| = 0 \text{ as } k \to \infty, \mu-a.e. $$

Show that the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $(f_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is Cauchy in almost every point,
2. $f_n \to f , \mu-a.e.$ for some function $f$ defined on $X$.

**My attempt.** I was able to show implication $(\Leftarrow)$ in the following way:

Suppose that $f_n \to f, \mu-a.e.$, i.e., that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ almost everywhere on $X$. Fix an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$: by definition of convergence, we know that there exists some $K \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $k > K$ we have that $|f_k(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon/2,$ almost everywhere on $X$. Then, for every $n,m \geqslant K$, we have that

$$ |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| = |f_n(x) - f(x) + f(x) - f_m(x))| \leqslant |f_n(x) - f(x)| + |f_m(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon, $$

almost everywhere on $X$. By definition of supremum, it follows that

$$ \sup_{m,n \geqslant K} |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \epsilon$$

almost everywhere on $X$, which finishes the proof of first implication.

Notice that this first implication is really similar to showing that a sequence of real numbers is convergent if and only if it is Cauchy.

As for the $(\Rightarrow)$ implication, I don't know if I can follow the exact same logic as in the case of sequences of real numbers: i.e., can I still say that $(f_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is bounded almost everywhere and then say that it admits a convergent ($\mu-a.e.$) subsequence and then doing the usual procedure to conclude that $(f_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is convergent $\mu-a.e.$ ?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @AnneBauval . The exercise is stated with $=0$ instead of $\to 0$ in the exercise sheet but I will assume that's a typo and that it should be $\to 0$ for now.  As for your second comment, all you're saying is that I should be more formal because $K$ might depend on the $x$ we fix, correct? But this doesn't change the reasoning that comes afterwards, correct?

Comment: @AnneBauval So, basically, I know that the sequence is Cauchy $\mu-a.e.$, i.e., $(f_n(x))$ is Cauchy for almost every $x \in X$. Fixing an arbitrary such $x$, this sequence is also convergent, since Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb R$ are also convergent. Therefore, the sequence $f_n(x)$ converges to some $f(x)$, for almost every $x$ in $X$ ?

Comment: Thanks. I understood your comments but I only have one further question: is there any difference between this Cauchy definition that is presented in the exercise and the usual Cauchy sequence definition, i.e., saying that a sequence $(f_n)$ is Cauchy if and only if $$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \Bbb N \colon \forall n,m \geqslant N,  |f_n - f_m| < \epsilon ? $$

Comment: Thanks once again @AnneBauval . If you care to elaborate an answer, I would gladly mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of Cauchy sequence that is presented in the exercise (with typo corrected: $\to0$ instead of $=0$) is equivalent to the usual one:
$$\sup_{m,n \ge k}d(y_m,y_n)\to0 \text{ as } k \to \infty$$
$$\iff\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\Bbb N,\forall k\ge N,\sup_{m,n\ge k}d(y_m,y_n)\le \epsilon$$
$$\iff\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\Bbb N,\forall k\ge N,\forall m,n\ge k,d(y_m,y_n)\le \epsilon$$
$$\iff\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \Bbb N,\forall m,n\ge N,d(y_m,y_n)\le \epsilon.$$

No surprise, then, that this equivalence "is really similar to showing that a sequence of real numbers is convergent if and only if it is Cauchy", $1⇐2$ being the "only if".

Strictly speaking, your proof for this $1⇐2$
is not correct, because $K$
should depend not only on $ϵ$
but also on $x$
(the latter being an arbitrary element of a well-chosen subset whose complement negligible). It *does* change the reasoning in making it correct, but at the cost of (formally) only few changes (crucial, though).

For $1⇒2$,
assume $(f_n(x))$
is Cauchy for every $x∈Y$,
for some co-negligible $Y$,
and simply use that every Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$
is convergent.  And for $⇐$
same thing: simply use that every convergent sequence is Cauchy (in any metric space). But again: take care, for $⇒$
as well as for $⇐$,
to fix $Y$
first (co-negligible and "well-chosen"), and then to fix $x∈Y$.